# Unmet dependencies trying to install samba, Ubuntu 22.04-2

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dependencies, samba

This is a one week old installation of Ubuntu 22.04.2. I have installed various programs successfully and want to share folders on the local network. When I go to this from Files it asks to install samba and that is failing with the message below.  I can add information about repositories but AskUbuntu/StackExchange seems to be preventing me adding them.   They're not exotic.

```
root@Clevo2:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 samba : Depends: python3-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
         Recommends: attr
         Recommends: python3-markdown but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@Clevo2:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

ADDITION 13.iv.23: output of `apt-cache policy samba python3-samba samba-common-bin libwbclient0 samba-libs`
Is as follows

```
root@Clevo2:/home/chris# apt-cache policy samba python3-samba samba-common-bin libwbclient0 samba-libs
samba:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
python3-samba:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
samba-common-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libwbclient0:
  Installed: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
samba-libs:
  Installed: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://mirror.infomaniak.ch/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
root@Clevo2:/home/chris#
```

I hope that points up the collision(s) and perhaps how to resolve them.

Comment: Try to install the packages that `samba` depends on first: `sudo apt install python3-samba samba-common-bin libwbclient0 samba-libs`.

Comment: From your question. but AskUbuntu/StackExchange seems to be preventing me adding them Please explain this statement.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `sudo apt-cache policy samba python3-samba samba-common-bin libwbclient0 samba-libs`

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first before `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Thanks all four.  Yes I ran `apt update` before attempting the install. Yes, I understand about the dependencies.  Explaining what I mean, hm, not sure what to add to the output from apt: the dependency version numbers are such that there are incompatibilities so the installation won't proceed.  `apt-cache policy` output added to the question.  Hope that helps, appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the post-inst script inside the package, basically disabling all functionality and repackaged into a separate .deb file.

I then installed this fixed .deb with dpkg and the rest of my upgrades went without a hitch.